# angular material color in vendor.js file

Tags: angular, angular-material

For some reason I cannot get the mat-progress-bar to show the color that I want!  It shows a purple color (#6200ee).  When I search for that particular color it is ONLY in the vendor.js file.

I have tried many of the different suggestions to overriding the progress-bar color and bring this in to my site.css file - but nothing is working.

**I guess my question is, where is vendor.js is getting this color from?**  Once I find out where this is coming from then I can ask how to override it.

Just to add a bit more detail.  I have a material-themes.css and a site.css that is both referenced.

In the material-themes.css file I updated the following:

```
.mat-progress-bar-background {
  fill: #005288; }

.mat-progress-bar-buffer {
  background-color: #005288; }

.mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
  background-color: #005288; }

.mat-progress-bar.mat-accent .mat-progress-bar-background {
  fill: #005288; }

.mat-progress-bar.mat-accent .mat-progress-bar-buffer {
  background-color: #005288; }

.mat-progress-bar.mat-accent .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
  background-color: #005288; }

.mat-progress-bar.mat-warn .mat-progress-bar-background {
  fill: #005288; }

.mat-progress-bar.mat-warn .mat-progress-bar-buffer {
  background-color: #005288; }

.mat-progress-bar.mat-warn .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
  background-color: #005288; }
```

All to this blue color #005288 -

When I look at site in the chrome tools the classes are translated to the `mat-mdc-` selector.  And in the vendor.js file I'm seeing the following type of code:

```
.mat-mdc-progress-bar[mode=query]
```

I'm guessing that the vendor.js is getting the colors from there and overriding my site.css and the material-themes.css

Just in case anyone is looking for the code:

```
<mat-progress-bar mode="query"></mat-progress-bar>
```

Answer (score 0):

if putting your code in the global `styles.css` doesn't help you can try different things:

1- using `!important` to override your style

2- using `/deep/`

for example:

```
 /deep/ .mat-progress-bar-buffer  {
  background-color: #005288 !important; }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer - I thought deep was being deprecated?